# Performing Functions on a List in F#

Tags: string, list, f#

Well I've been at it for almost 10 hours trying to solve this in F#

**I need to sort the list in alphabetical order and reverse the list**

- I do not even know where to begin to sort them alphabetically..
- The reverse list only returns a list with  for all 10 elements
  Someone please help me

What I have come up with:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
 printfn "Enter 10 Names";;
 let mutable list = [for i in 1 .. 10 -> System.Console.ReadLine(); ]
 printfn "%A" list
 //let list = List.sort
 //printfn "%A" list
 let reverseList list = List.fold (fun acc elem -> elem::acc) [] list
 printfn "%A" (reverseList [for i in 1 .. 10 -> List.iteri])
```

Comment: When I click run code snippet nothing happens, we should report this to meta

Comment: Run code snippet doesn't work for F# - only for html/js

Comment: See `List.sort` and `List.rev`

Comment: Like I said, ive been reviewing the library for 10 hours trying to create this program. With obviously an intensive study on List.sort and List.rev. I can't get anywhere at this point

Answer (score 5):

```
    [<EntryPoint>]
    printfn "Enter 10 Names";;
    let list = [for i in 1 .. 10 -> System.Console.ReadLine(); ]
    printfn "%A" list
    // List.sort takes 'list' as a parameter and returns sorted list 
    //(in the case of string list - alphabetically)
    let sortedlist = List.sort list
    printfn "%A" sortedlist
    // List.rev takes 'sortedlist' as a parameter and returns reversed list
    let sortedreversedlist = List.rev sortedlist
    printfn "%A" sortedreversedlist
```

Or you can pass results of List.sort function as argument into List.rev function without assigning it to the variable:

```
let sortedreversedlist' =  List.rev (List.sort list)
printfn "%A" sortedreversedlist'
```

Also F# has pipe operator '|>' that could be used to create 'pipeline' operations on the list (redirect results of previous function into next). It allows to write the same sequence of functions differently (in the order they will be performed):

```
let sortedreversedlist'' = list |> List.sort |> List.rev
printfn "%A" sortedreversedlist''
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, the thread is pretty old enough, but another option using pattern matching and abstracting away the predicate logic would be:

```
let reverseComparer expr =
match expr with
    | true -> -1
    | false -> 1
    | _ -> 0

let reversedNames = names |> List.sortWith (fun previous follower -> reverseComparer (previous > follower))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let list = [ "bbc"; "CNN"; "cnn"; "abc"; "1"; "ABC"; "BBC"; "2"]
    let sortedList = Set.toList( Set.ofList list )
    let reversedList = List.rev sortedList;;
```